# How to write good test?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, dapps, hardhat, testing

My idea on writing test is very low, i can't write test, teach me how to write test? It is so confusing for me. All i know is seeing what the function is doing and check it is working properly or not. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Writing good tests is an important aspect of software development as it helps you verify that your code is working as expected and helps catch any bugs early in the development process. Here are some tips on how to write good tests:

Test One Thing at a Time: Each test should test one thing, and only one thing. This helps you isolate the cause of any failures and makes it easier to understand why a test is failing.

Test Both Positive and Negative Cases: Test both expected and unexpected behavior. This helps you catch potential bugs and edge cases.

Use Test Data that is Easy to Understand: Use test data that is easy to understand and readable. This makes it easier to understand why a test is failing and also helps make your tests self-documented.

Make Tests Independent: Tests should be independent from each other and not depend on the order in which they are run. This helps prevent cascading failures and makes it easier to understand why a test is failing.

Test the Public Interface: Test the public interface of your code and avoid testing internal details. This makes your tests more robust and less prone to breaking when the implementation changes.

Avoid Hardcoded Values: Avoid hardcoded values in your tests and use variables instead. This makes it easier to change the test data as needed and also helps make your tests self-documented.

Write Tests that are Fast: Tests should run quickly so that you can run them often. If a test is slow, you might be less likely to run it as frequently as you should.

Keep Tests up-to-date: When changes are made to the code, make sure to update the tests accordingly. This helps you catch any bugs early and ensures that your tests continue to be effective.

Use Assertions: Use assertions in your tests to verify that the expected values are returned. Assertions are a way of checking that the code behaves as expected and will throw an error if the check fails.

By following these tips, you can write effective tests that help you catch bugs early and make your code more reliable.

Comment: Though this is the ChatGPT answer, all aspects are really well summarized.